# Sort an array of numbers and strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array of numbers and strings. like

```
NSArray* list = @[@"9", @"21", @"A 2-5", @"19-1", @"10", @"D 7-10", @"13-2"];
```

I want this array sorted as

```
@[@"9", @"10", @"21", @"13-2", @"19-1", @"A 2-5", @"D 7-10"];
```

But if I use

```
[list sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

I get

```
@[@"10", @"13-2", @"19-1", @"21", @"9", @"A 2-5", @"D 7-10"];
```

I get similar result too if I use

```
[list sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

How can I achieve the result as I expected?

Comment: Use `return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];`.

Comment: even better (y) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `sortedArrayUsingComparator`. Here is how you can implement it:

```
NSArray* list = @[@"9", @"21", @"A 2-5", @"19-1", @"10", @"D 7-10", @"13-2"];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray *sortedList = [list sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *string1, NSString *string2) {
        NSNumber *number1 = [numberFormatter numberFromString:string1];
        NSNumber *number2 = [numberFormatter numberFromString:string2];

        if (number1 && number2)
            return [number1 compare:number2];
        else if (number1)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (number2)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else return [string1 compare:string2];
}];
NSLog(@"sortedList: %@", sortedList);
```

Output:

> (
>       9,
>       10,
>       21,
>       "13-2",
>       "19-1",
>       "A 2-5",
>       "D 7-10" )

The reason why you can't use `integerValue` instead of `NSNumberFormatter` is that, for instance, it will parse `13-2` as `13` and it will go before `21`, which is not what you expect. NSNumberFormatter is a bit more flexible and will return nil if a string is not exactly a number.

Comment: I was trying with converting to integer value, as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: This is the hardest way possible to perform the sort.

Comment: @rmaddy You make me feel ignorant :)

Comment: @alexburtnik That's OK. Ignorance is easily fixed through education. :) No one can possibly know all available APIs.

Comment: @x4h1d Please uncheck the accepted answer, so that I can delete the misleading solution

Comment: @alexburtnik Your solution isn't wrong. It's just that there are simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that you *do not* have "an array of numbers and strings", you have an array of `Strings`. They are compared based on the character sequence: compare the first character, if the first character is the same, compare the second character, etc. This results in the order you are getting.

If you want the order you specified, you will need to implement a custom comparator / sorting method ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805589/3572942) shows the possibilities nicely).